# Add Cancel Button to a Custom Meta Box

Tags: plugins, metabox, buttons

Any ideas how I could add a cancel button, like the default one in the Publish meta box, to a custom meta box?

The standard code is `<a href="#visibility" class="cancel-post-visibility hide-if-no-js button-cancel">Cancel</a>` I guess it's using some js to do the cancel/reset action so it's not easy to replicate.

I basically want to add a button that will clear an input field in my meta box. `input type=reset` will clear all the fields on the page, so I wanted to see if I could use WP's toolset.

Open to ideas for the best solution here.

Comment: Have you added a cancel button? Even if it's non-functional, I think you can ignore the whole metabox/WP thing and treat this as a pure "I have a series on input form elements inside of a div container, how do I clear them when a link is clicked?". If you're looking for a WP specific way to do this though, there isn't one

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a Wordpress-specific way to do this. If there isn't something like that, then I can use a line of js to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
<a class="clear_button hide-if-no-js button-cancel" title="clear" data-clear style="text-decoration:underline;">Clear</a>
```

It does the job. I was hoping for something more "Wordpressy" but don't see a metabox cancel function.